# Calculate number of matching properties in Redis

Tags: redis

I'd like to see if a migration of a dataset from PostgreSQL to Redis has a positive influence on a particular search query. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to organize the keys and values.

What I want is a that users are able to supply a list of properties and the application delivers a list of items in an ascending order of properties that have not been entered.

For example:

```
Item #1 { prop1, prop2, prop4, prop7 }     Query: "prop1 prop3 prop4 prop5"
Item #2 { prop7, prop8 }                   Result: Item #3
Item #3 { prop2, prop3, prop5 }                    Item #1
                                                   Item #2
```

What I have come up with so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
properties = (1, 3, 4, 5)
items = ["Properties:%s:items" % id for property in properties ]
redis.zunionstore("query:related_items", items)
redis.zinterstore("query:result", { "Items:all": 1, "query:related_items": -1 })
```

This builds a sorted set of `Item`s (all with a score of 1) that are connected with the user-entered `Property`s. Afterwards, an intersection with the sorted set of all `Items` (where each value's score is the number of `Property`s) is calculated. The weights are set to create a score of 0 if all `Property`s of an `Item` are supplied in the query.

As the number of `Item`s is about 600.000 entries this query takes approximately 4-6 seconds. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: This question is asking for a bounty :)

Comment: Another small step in the direction of increasing performance that I made is this: As the web interface allows users to filter on other criteria as well, I built separate `ZSETs` for each filter setting which have fewer entries than one single `ZSET` with all entries would have (i.e. `Properties:%s:filter1-on:filter2-off:items`).

This helps a lot, but only if other filters are in use. Without filters the huge `ZSET` is used as usually.

Comment: How many different properties are there? The question is a bit cryptic to me, e.g. what are the sorting conditions?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I'll try to clarify: There are about 2000 properties and this is not going to change much in the future. The sorting condition is that those Items whose properties have all been met are displayed on top. Followed by Items where only one property was not specified, followed again by those with two missing properties and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're looking for a Python solution, but the [Ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/) library for Ruby is my favorite of the Redis-based database analogues. Considering the similarities between Python and Ruby and Ohm's [exceptional documentation](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/Ohm/Model.html), you might find some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Used real properties as stated in comments.

I think I did it (once more). I used [PHPRedis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis).

I used sorted sets too, but I inverted your schema: Each zset represents an **ingredient**, and each **recipe id** is a member of that zset. So every zset has the **same number of members**, i.e., every recipe on the application. Every recipe **uses** or not a ingredient. That defines the score.

Loading is somewhat expensive, but query is done **under 3s**, for a sample with 12  ingredients and 600.000 recipes. (you've got a lot of them for sure!).

---

### Loading

Pseudo-code:

```
For every ingredient i on the system
   For every recipe j on the system
      If recipe j uses the ingredient i Then
         score = 1
         INCR recipe:j:ing_count //Will help sorting
         RPUSH recipe:j:ing_list i //For listing all ingredients in recipe
      Else
         score = 0
      End If
      ZADD ing:i score j
   End For
End For
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
### Total of ingredients
define('NUM_OF_ING',12);

### Total of recipes
define('NUM_OF_RECIPES',600000);

$redis = new \Redis();
$redis->connect('localhost');

for ($ing=1; $ing<=NUM_OF_ING; $ing++) {
    for ($recipe=1; $recipe<=NUM_OF_RECIPES; $recipe++) {
        $score = rand() % 2;
        if ($score == 1) {
            $redis->incr("recipe:$recipe:ing_count");
            $redis->rpush("recipe:$recipe:ing_list", $ing);
        }
        $redis->zAdd("ing:$ing", $score, $recipe);
    }
}
echo "Done.\n";
?>
```

---

### Querying

Before I paste the PHP code and measured running time, let me do some observations:

Sorting is done based on the number of ingredients used (**sum** of the zsets in query). If two recipes use  **all ingredients that are in query**, then the tie-break is done by the number of additional ingredients that one recipe has. More ingredients, higher position.

The sum is handled by [ZINTERSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore). The zset with sums is stored in **result**.

Then a [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) command looks in the count key for each recipe, tailoring the order with this additional constraint.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
$redis = new \Redis();
$redis->connect('localhost');

//properties in query
$query = array('ing:2', 'ing:4', 'ing:5');
$weights = array(1, 1, 1);

//intersection
$redis->zInter('result', $query, $weights, 'sum');

//sorting
echo "Result:\n";
var_dump($redis->sort('result', array('by'=>'recipe:*:ing_count', 'sort'=>'desc', 'limit'=>array(0,10))));
echo "End.\n";
?>
```

Output and running time:

```
niloct@Impulse-Ubuntu:~$ time ./final2.php 
Result:
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "5230"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "79549"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "2871"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "336"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "109279"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "5352"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "16868"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "690"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "3174"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "8795"
}
End.

real    0m2.930s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.004s
niloct@Impulse-Ubuntu:~$ redis-cli lrange recipe:5230:ing_list 0 -1
 1) "12"
 2) "11"
 3) "10"
 4) "9"
 5) "8"
 6) "7"
 7) "6"
 8) "5"
 9) "4"
10) "3"
11) "2"
12) "1"
```

Hope that helps.

PS: Can you post your performance measures after trying this ?

Comment: So, have you tried the solution ? I presume you didn't reply because the timing was different to you. The machine I'm now (from which I posted) keeps consistently taking 2.5s for the ZINTERSTORE, which is the command that matters.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with it. I just tried your solution and it performs fast enough for my needs. One problem that remains is that I not only want Items that have the most matching properties to appear first, but rather those with the least missing properties. As a secondary sorting condition the plain number of properties. That's why Item #3 is ranked higer than Item #1 in the example. Do you have an idea how to accomplish that in your solution?

Comment: Thanks again. I noticed that this is not quite what I want because, now, Items rank high when plenty properties match, but it shouldn't be about how many properties match but rather how few properties didn't match. Think of items as recipes and properties as ingredients and I want those recipes for that all ingredients are specified by the user. I hope that made it clearer.

Comment: Show me a real test case which behaves oddly, and the expected behavior please.

Comment: Consider the following: `Item1` w/ `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, `Item #2 ` w/ `p1`, `p2`, `p3`. Both get the same ranking when the user enters only `p1 p2 p3` because `p4` does not get included in the calculation.  But `Item #2` should rank higher than `Item #1` because it is a perfect match and there's no property missing.

Comment: I see the point, recipes that have all ingredients in the query should be listed in order of "perfect matching", regarding the other ingredients for each recipe ? So first all perfect matches, then all recipes that have one ingredient more than those in the query, and so on ? What about the secondary sorting condition regarding ingredient "number" ? I fail to see how that matters in the real example.

Comment: Exactly! I'm sorry for not being able to express that correctly. The second condition should be that a recipe with 5 ingredients should rank higher than a recipe with only 3 ingredients, although both are matched completely. We have a lot of recipes with only 2-4 ingredients but don't want them to be on top all the time when more sophisticated recipes are also cookable.

Comment: What you said now conflicts with the above comment `Consider the following (...)`. `Item #2` was a perfect match to the query, but now you're saying that since `Item #1` has an additional ingredient and matches, it should appear higher. What is the correct rule ? I am calling `perfect match` when recipe has exactly all ingredients from query and no other more.

Comment: No no, I don't want `Item1` to appear higher. In my comment `Consider the following (...)`, I was explaining that your solution did not consider the ingredients which the user did not enter, therefore `Item1` and `Item2` had an equal score, although Item2 should appear higher because it is a perfect match. Sorry, if I'm confusing you.

Comment: Edited the answer. I can be reached by e-mail if you need more work done (see profile), but I believe you will accept it this time =)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solutions still suffers from the problem that only  those ingredients play a role in calculating a match that the user entered, the ones that are missing from the user input and therefore are not present for cooking a recipe are much more important. I elaborated what I tried to describe in the original question [here](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1jT3DrSldegq8F1Qtz6Obsd3zXlBYmwYCDTu83BILSlA). If you want, you can reply to me via the email address that I posted in my profile's description because regular users cannot see each other's email addresses.